# From + noun + on / onward / forward / forth / ahead

Tags: word-choice, expressions

Which word would we use if we were going to use a "specific time" or "specific place" instead of the noun?
How would you fill the blanks bellow?

**1)From tonight (................) .** (on / onward / forward / forth / ahead)

**2)From this line (................) .**  (on / onward / forward / forth / ahead)

**3)From this page(................) .** (on / onward / forward / forth / ahead)

Answer (score 1):

I would always use "onward" (or "onwards") for all three.

As a possible exception to that, I might sometimes use just "on" for "From this line".

Answer (score -1):

1 - From tonight **ahead**
2 - From this line **forward**
3 - From this page **forward**.

I don't know how to explain why I have chosen these ones, I can't explain the difference between forward, onward, ahead and forth, I just filled out the fields with the ones that make more sense to me.

Comment: Deniz Thanks. Where are you from? And do all of your people use it in this way or not necessarily?

Comment: I don't necessary live in a country that speaks English, I live in Brazil, but I have already seen many of these words and prepositions used in these contexts; 'line', 'page'.. is always used with "forward". It's hard to explain why, since English isn't necessary learnt by single words and verbs, if you really want to get the meaning of something, you have to see it in different contexts,  but here is my little explaination about "forward": 
Forward is a preposition, that means: go straight, in the target direction, when used with line or page it means: next: From this page to the next ones..

Comment: @YazdanSamieiPoor
You are reviewing some articles in a magazine with a friend, and he says: "Go forward' it means to go to the next page, in my point of view, "foward" is used when talking about something physical, differently from 'Ahead', Ahead doesn't necessary mean something physical, for instance: You are telling your friend a history, and he says: 'Go ahead' - 'Continue the history'. It doesn't refer to a physical thing, as you can see. Here are some examples of sentences with the preposition forward:  http://www.manythings.org/sentences/words/forward/1.html

Comment: Bear in mind that Forward can also be used to express hope, expectation and anxiously: I look forward to seeing you again; I look forward to tomorrow, I'm looking forward to my birthday